# Google Drive API resumable upload issue - wrong size in Range in response header

Tags: google-drive-api

I am experiencing a problem with Google Drive upload using my own library.

The problem is that when I send a `PUT` request with the first chunk with the following headers:

```
[0] => Content-Range: bytes 0-1054143/*
[1] => Content-Type: application/zip
[2] => Content-Length: 1054144
```

Google API returns the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 308 Resume Incomplete
Range: bytes=0-1048575
X-Range-MD5: 59ef685eb8e1ca4c5ebab6f11ab9f7c3
Date: Fri, 30 Jan 2015 12:34:35 GMT
Server: UploadServer ("Built on Jan 7 2015 15:51:42 (1420674702)")
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.02
```

There is a difference between the range I send (0-1054143) and the API stores (0-1048575).

Accordingly, once all of the chunks are sent to the API, the last range they return back is different than the size of the file I am trying to upload.

I use `*` in the `Content-Range` since the file size is unknown until the last chunk is read.

Any help?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the whole problem was the size of the chunk I send to the server. In [the docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable) is written:

> Chunk size restriction: All chunks must be a multiple of 256 KB (256 x 1024 bytes) in size, except for the final chunk that completes the upload. If you use chunking, it is important to keep the chunk size as large as possible to keep the upload efficient.

Once I have changed the size of the chunk I send, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The server is telling you in the response how many bytes it processed.  You need to pay attention to that.  Maybe there is an encoding problem where you aren't sending as many as you think? Or try sending a different chunk size, maybe what it received?